# How to use single quotes and double quotes value in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

This is mysql query

```
SELECT p_id, model_number, brand_name FROM tbl_products where model_number="Sha\"sha\'dd\"d"
```

I have following table and value [image]

you can see second row have same value, but while selecting it is not working. Any help will be appreciate able.

Comment: from where are you sending the query?

Comment: Couldn't understand.

Comment: is this a PHP Code which executes this query or something else?
Or phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape quotes and backslashes with backslashes.

Like this:

```
where model_number="Sha\\\"sha\\\'dd\\\"d"
```

Or you can simply use backticks as quotes around the value to interpret the value literally as raw string (this is not standard SQL but works in MySQL):

```
where model_number=`Sha\"sha\'dd\"d`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html

Under the Table 10.1

There list all Special Character Escape Sequences and some other way:

> There are several ways to include quote characters within a string:
>
> “'” inside a string quoted with “'” may be written as “''”.
>
> “"” inside a string quoted with “"” may be written as “""”.
>
> Precede the quote character by an escape character (“\”).
>
> “'” inside a string quoted with “"” needs no special treatment and
>   need not be doubled or escaped. In the same way, “"” inside a string
>   quoted with “'” needs no special treatment.

Follow this rule, your SQL can be written as:

```
where model_number="Sha\\\"sha\\\'dd\\\"d"
```

or

```
"Sha\\""sha\\''dd\\""d"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i tried above queries. It does not work.

Comment: can you run this SQL command? `SELECT "Sha\\""sha\\''dd\\""d"` and show me the result?

Comment: this is output Sha\\""sha\\''dd\\""d. It will work by simple select. In where condition only not working.